# C and exceptions

Tags: c, exception

In my the host part of my OpenCL code I've got a bunch of

```
  ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, ...
  ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, ...
  ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, ...
  ...
```

and instead of each time doing

```
  if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to write to source array!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

I'd like to know whether there is a way to somewhat wait for one "ret" to be unsuccessful to exit.

I'm aware (just aware, never used them) of the `signal()` and `raise()` functions but I'm not sure if I can use them here.

Comment: Putting the return value check into a function like so `ExitIfFails(clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, ...` doesn't work for you?

Comment: I use something similar to Jason's suggestion: I use a macro wrapper around my functions that would set the variable ret to the return code, then goto some cleanup code otherwise.  I know gotos are evil, but it's the best way I've found :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to keep it simple stick an "if" statement after each call with a custom error message. Sound like a lot but look at the amount of code a "try/catch" block needs.

"signals" are there to handle hardware alerts and inter process communication. Using them to fake exceptions will lead you into a world of pain and misery.

Given that the "try/catch" is just a heavily disguised "goto" you could try:

```
  ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, ...
  if (ret) goto catcher;
  ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, ... 
  if (ret) goto catcher;
  ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, ...
  if (ret) goto catcher;
  goto finalizer;
catcher:
  printf("Error: Failed to write to source array!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
finalizer:
   ..........
```

Comment: I would just like to add: BE VERY CAREFUL using this pattern.  I used this in my last OpenCL project but forgot the goto finalizer line and everything was failing like crazy.  I'd prefer to swap the catch and finally sections, with a goto at the end of catch.

Comment: @dwarduk -- I myself prefer the "lots of ifs" solution. Using goto for anything is like sticking your big toe into a gun barrel and hoping for the best. Using "signal" for anything other than it was designed for is like taking up smoking in a firework factory.

Comment: If you use this method, you might want to consider wrapping it in a macro to avoid such mistakes

Comment: @JamesAnderson -- I wasn't advocating using signal?  And while I dislike the lots of ifs, what I was suggesting was actually just restructuring this into: main code, cleanup, error handling, with the error handling ending in `goto finalizer`: I find myself always forgetting the goto line before error handling code begins otherwise.

Comment: @dwarduk: I get your point, but then you need a "goto" to get around the "catcher", Although you could put all the catchers at the end of the function after the normal return. I coded it up this way make it as similar to try/catch as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything wrong with:

```
if ((ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, ...)) != CL_SUCCESS ||
    (ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, ...)) != CL_SUCCESS ||
    (ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, ...)) != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Error: Failed to write to source array!\n");
    exit(1);
}
else
    ...do whatever it is that depends on everything else having succeeded...
```

And, if the error reporting code isn't going to use the value in `ret`, then you can do without the assignment and simplify that to:

```
if (clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, ...) != CL_SUCCESS ||
    clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, ...) != CL_SUCCESS ||
    clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, ...) != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Error: Failed to write to source array!\n");
    exit(1);
}
else
    ...do whatever it is that depends on everything else having succeeded...
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle exceptions in C is to make use of the perror call to get the result/status of the last performed action.

Here is a reference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror

Comment: There are a couple of issues here.  First, `perror()` is certainly better than nothing, but it reports on the value of `errno`, and it is far from clear that the OpenCL code will be setting `errno`, or even returning `errno` values.  Second, it is an infuriatingly limiting function; you can supply one string that is prepended to the error message.  It does, however, write to standard error.  More to the point, though, suggesting 'use `perror()`' really doesn't address the question.  Do you mean 'use `perror()` in place of the `printf()`'?  Or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: If perror() fails, it returns a non zero code. That could be used to check before evaluation

Comment: We're obviously not talking about the same function — the [`perror()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/perror.html) I'm referring to has a return type of `void`.